# How to write a script to send messages over telegram-cli?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, schedule, telegram

I don't know how to explain myself but I need to send scheduled messages via telegram so I downloaded the telegram client to send messages via terminal. I wrote a bash script that opens the client, everything here is going according to plan then it opens the telegram command line and my script doesn't run accordingly. How can I make work?

[image: this is the telegram command line]

This is the script, nothing difficult:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ospite/tg
bin/telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub //opening telegram client
sleep 30
chat_with_peer Antonio //it doesn't work because it's not the debian shell anymore
done
```

Comment: For very simple cases, you *may* be able to pipe a command sequence via standard input, either using `echo`, `printf` (better), or a [here-document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) using `cat`. For more complicated interactions, you will probably need to use something like [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu!Please open a terminal and issue the command `lsb_release -a` and [edit] the output into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To write a script to send messages over telegram-cli, you need to do the following:

1. Move to the directory where telegram-cli is:
2. Open *telegram-cli* with your key
3. Load your contact list with `-W`
4. Send the message to anyone on your contact list previously loaded

To achieve that:

```
cd /path/to/tg && bin/telegram-cli -W server.pub -e "msg contact message"
```

or

```
cd /path/to/tg && (sleep 1; echo "contact_list"; sleep 1; echo "msg contact message") | bin/telegram-cli -W -k server.pub
```

More info here: https://github.com/vysheng/tg

Comment: you sir, saved my day

Comment: What if I want to make the actually message a variable that is passed along? 

I tried

    /telegram-cli -W server.pub -e 'msg @user $1'

But the only message sent then is $1.. not the actual text.

Comment: If you use single quotes, $1 is interpreted literaly, meaning, it is not interpreted as a reference to a variable. Use double quotes instead. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html#Single-Quotes

Comment: any better way to do this in 2022?